# Switching Classes during __construct()

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor, magic-methods

Let's take the following classes for a moment:

```
class member {
    public $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;

        // Check user level
        if ($this->check_user_level() == moderator) {
            $this = new moderator($this->id);
        }
    }

    private function check_user_level() {
        // Return user level from system based on user ID
    }
}

class moderator extends member {
    public function show_moderator_tools() {
        // etc.
    }
}

==================

$user = new member($user_id);
```

The desired behavior is to have `$user` detect whether the user is authorized to have moderator access, and if so recast the user using the `moderator` class instead of `member`.

PHP forbids simply reassigning `$this`, so what appears to be the best solution would be one of the following:

**Run `check_user_level($id)` as a regular function and using an if statement**

```
$user_level = check_user_level($id);

if ($user_level == "moderator") {
    $user = new moderator($id);
} else {
    $user = new member($id);
}
```

**Set a flag in the base class that can be used for a check/redefinition after initializing `$user`**

```
$user = new member($id);

if ($user->flag = TRUE) {
    $user = new moderator($id);
}
```

The latter feels like it's introducing a security flaw, especially since the flag (which could just as easily be `$user->user_level`, or similar, I guess) would have to be public to be able to check it afterward.

What I would *like* to do would be to just make one call to `new member($id)` and have it handle things automatically from there, without the need for if statements after the fact.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of do this by introducing another class (lets call it `user`) and using the [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method in php and [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) for calling the methods.
The logic is something like this - 
Create a `user` class that has no method except `check_user_level`. It checks proper details and assigns it's `$obj` to the instance of either `member` or `moderator` class.

Here is how the classes would look like (I've changed the functions to print something out)-

```
class user{
    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        if ($this->check_user_level() == "moderator") {
            $this->obj = new moderator($this->id);
        }else{
            $this->obj = new member($this->id);
        }
    }

    public function __call($method, $args){
        call_user_func_array(array($this->obj,$method), $args);
    }

    public function __get($prop){
        if(isset($this->obj->$prop)){
            return $this->obj->$prop;    
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    private function check_user_level() {
        // Return user level from system based on user ID
        if($this->id == 1){
            return "moderator";
        }
        return "member";
    }
}

class member {
    public $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function show_message($arg){
        var_dump($this->id.$arg);
    }
}

class moderator extends member{
    public function show_moderator_tools() {
        var_dump($this->id ."My toolset!");
    }
}
```

So, now you can simply call the `user` class and that will automatically decide if it's a `member` or a `moderator` and call the method if it exists.

```
//Trying out a few examples
//Creating a member user
$mem_obj = new user(213);
$mem_obj->show_message("New message");

//Creating a moderator user
$mod_obj = new user(1);
$mod_obj->show_moderator_tools();

/*
OUTPUTS
-------
string(14) "213New message"
string(12) "1My toolset!"
*/
```

But you need to be careful with these kind of hacks.
For instance -

```
//This will fail
//because mem_obj doesn't have show_moderator_tools()
$mem_obj->show_moderator_tools();
```

**EDIT**
You can similarly go ahead with redirecting to properties using [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).
I have modified the code above to add this method beneath `__call`.

```
//Testing it
var_dump($mem_obj->id);
//This is an illegal property
var_dump($mem_obj->illegelProperty);
/*
OUTPUTS
int(213)
NULL
*/
```

Comment: Just tested it out, and it works beautifully!  I'm not quite certain on the specifics of how, but I think I'm starting to get it.  Essentially, each object is in fact an instance of `user` that has another object of the appropriate user level class embedded at $this->obj.  If something that is not part of `user` gets called, then __call() directs it to run the corresponding function within the nested object.  Is that about on the mark?

Comment: @Kaji Yep, Thats the whole idea :)

Comment: Awesome!  Is it possible to set up properties to work the same way as well?

Comment: @Kaji yep, you can do that as well. Will edit in 10 mins

Comment: @Kaji Checkout the edit and have a look at PHP magic methods links :)

Comment: Beautiful!  I'd been trying to figure out how to use some of the magic methods in the past, but got a bit lost.  You've just provided a great, clear example of how to use these two.  Thanks again!